# Error when graphing function

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
function solve_heat_equation(T,N_time,N_space,A,B)
delta_t=T/N_time; 
delta_x=1/N_space; 
rho=delta_t/delta_x^2;
phi=zeros(N_space+1,N_time+1);
phi(:,1)=initial_condition((0:N_space)*delta_x);
for j=1:N_time;
    for i=2:N_space;
    phi(i,j+1)=rho*(phi(i-1,j)+phi(i+1,j))+(1-2*rho)*phi(i,j);
    end;
    phi(1,j+1)= (-2*A*delta_x - 4*phi(2,j+1) + phi(3,j+1))/-3;
    phi(N_space+1,j+1)=(2*B*delta_x+4*phi(N_space,j+1)+phi(N_space-1,j+1))/3;
end;
```

For reference, initial condition is:

```
function z=initial_condition(x);
z=0.5-abs(0.5-x);
```

The above function works perfectly; however, when I try and graph the results with the followign function, I get an error.

> ??? Error using ==> solve_heat_equation Too many output arguments.
>
> Error in ==> check_solution_to_heat_equation at 46
>       phi = solve_heat_equation(T,N_time,N_space, A, B);

```
clear all;
hold on;
grid on;
N_time = 1000;
N_space = 50;
A = 1;
B =1;
delta_x=1/N_space; 
x_var=(0:N_space)*delta_x;

for T=[0.01,0.05,0.25,0.5];
    phi = solve_heat_equation(T,N_time,N_space, A, B);
    plot(x_var,phi);
end;
```

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong and any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to extract a return value from the function, but you haven't declared any return arguments when you wrote the function.

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
function phi = solve_heat_equation(T,N_time,N_space,A,B)
...
```

Comment: I still get the same error. Instead of returning the last entry of the matrix phi, the MATLAB output is now all the entries of the matrix phi when I define this function as phi. But either way it doesn't allow me to graph it still.

Comment: @user: Then I don't understand what you are trying to do.  What do you want the return value of your function to represent?

Comment: I want it to be the final row of the matrix that it calculates.

Comment: @user: Then you will need to write code to make it do that,  `phi = phi(end,:)`.